# How to save LocalGPO for non-administrator group

Tags: security, version-control, policies

Windows 7, 32 bit.  I have added the "Group Policy Object" to the MMC with group selected as "non-administrators" (from [browse]-->Users).  I have locked down the capabilities of the local machine so that non-administrators can do very little, and now I want to be able to apply this policy setting to clones of this machine.  Further, I want to be able to put these settings into source control so that policy modifications can be tracked.  I want the administrators to have full capabilities.

Once configured on my target machine, I have created a WIM with the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT) which solves the first half of my needs but this makes it hard to compare any changes to the policy.

I have installed the Security Compliance Manager (SCM) but this wants a baseline to start with and I do not see how to apply policies to groups with this tool.  I have installed the LocalGPO.wsf tool as well and have created a backup of the local policy with the /Export switch, but when I use the MMC to change the non-administrator policies, this is not reflected with the LocalGPO.wsf when I run the /Compare against my previously exported GPO.  We cracked open the LocalGPO.wsf file and at first glance it looks like it calls SECEDIT.exe which does not seem to take any switches for group policies.

Am I missing a switch on the LocalGPO.wsf that will export the non-administrator group policy settings so that I can put this into source control?

Is there another way to apply my changes to the non-administrators in the SCM?  I could not find that menu item.

Are my aspirations too high to be able to update these policies in a controlled fashion?

Thanks - Steve

Answer (score 1):

%windir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers

Unhide files

or

MMC add Group Policy Object Editor -> Users Tab -> Non-Administrators Policy

Expand User Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts > Logon; Click Add; Click Browse; It will open up the folder containing scripts. If you go up two folders you will find the folder to copy to other machines (for me it was called S-1-5-32-545).

Comment: This seems to be consensus for how to deploy by copying the folders even under Win10. See this [posting](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/7d061d7e-275a-44df-a3f3-3d92378316af/how-to-export-nonadministrators-local-gpo-for-import-on-a-different-pc?forum=w7itprosecurity&prof=required) from 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know the answer to this as well. I recently made a Windows 7 kiosk and I'd like to export the changes I made in non-administrators for future reference. It seems that gpresult only looks at what is applied from a domain level.